# reCAPTCHA Error Node.js: Error: Unknown base64 encoding at char: �

Tags: node.js, express, recaptcha

I am implementing reCAPTCHA v3 into my Node.js express project.

But i only get this error in the browser.

[image: reCAPTCHA Error]

My used code snippets.

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=6LdgLsMUAAAAAA8CUb0vMjpgCoUTKRYrRYbZFtLB' async defer></script>
```

this is my code for the frontend

```
        const token = await grecaptcha.execute('6LdgLsMUAAAAAA8CUb0vMjpgCoUTKRYrRYbZFtLB', { action: 'handy' })

        const result = await $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json",
            url: '/getPhones/submitData',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                Token: token
            })
        });

        var htmlCode = SON.stringify(await result.json());
        grid.innerHTML = htmlCode;
```

And here is my backend

```
router.post("/submitData", async(req, res, ) => {
    const fbUpload = require("../server/fb");

    const result = JSON.parse(
        await request
        .post("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify")
        .form({
            secret: secretKey,
            response: req.body.Token,
            remoteip: req.ip
        })
    )

res.send(result)
```